# BackboneJS - How to fetch external RSS feeds and display in View

Tags: backbone.js, rss

I want to create a Backbone View which contains RSS feeds from different external pages ( I got permission!) - So what I would like to know is how to approach this?! Should I use the RESTful API thing since I either have to fetch the JSON or XML? And/or should I create a model and a collection? Something like:

```
function($, Backbone) {
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "link/path to website where I want to fetch the RSS",

    defaults: {
        "title": '',
        "description": '',
        "pubDate": '',
        "link": ''
    }
});

return Model;

});

function(Backbone, Model) {
    var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Model,

});

return Collection;
});
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that AJAX requests to other websites are difficult and discouraged: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
I would recommend to parse the RSS feed on your server and re-format it in JSON. Then, you wouldn't need any modification on your model except setting the URL to your own server.